# segfault not caught in gdb nor valgrind

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind, realloc

I have a fairly big code written in c++ (not by me).
The code has been working fine for the most part, until I upgraded the system where it is running to a newer version of debian (bullseye).

We are getting a segfault when one specific operation of the code is executed.

I get the segfault with the code compiled in both optimized and debug flavors.

However, when I run the code with either gdb or valgrind, the code works fine. Valgrind doesn't show any errors.

The last thing I tried was running the code *without* gdb/valgrind and generating a core dump. Opening the core dump with gdb shows that the segfault happens when I call realloc(), so apparently something is messing up that pointer when it is freed. I tried replacing the realloc by a malloc() followed by a memcpy() (without freeing the previous pointer), and it worked fine.

I was reading in other blogs and it might be that both gdb and valgrind change the memory layout of the code so the bug doesn't show up, so if that's the case, how can I track it ?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could also try building with `-fsanitize=address` and see if this catchtes the issue. Other than that, could you trace the pointee object to get an idea where it might be used after freeing it?

Comment: `realloc` etc in C++ are a red-flag, as most uses of them in a typical `C` way lead to Undefined Behaviour.  I would start by examining all use of low-level `C` memory calls in the application code to check for UB.

Comment: While a sanitizer (as suggested by @lubgr) is preferable, you could also add a log of debugging output. Print the pointers, print returned values, make sure you have plenty of error checking, and print array and pointer indexes.

Comment: Probably enable aslr in GDB with `set disable-randomization off`.

Comment: Do you ever perform a realloc of size 0? That is not well defined and may vary between platforms (and what Valgrind does). As an example, on macOS realloc of size zero frees the original and then allocates a minimum sized object. Valgrind just frees the memory.

Comment: It is a bit odd that use of gdb should obscure the segmentation fault, but you can get around this by making sure that the program is able to dump core (for example, making sure that your "ulimit -c" value is suitable), running the program to let it dump core, then looking at the core with gdb.

Comment: @TimBoddy Actually no, debuggers could set certain memory areas to special values. For example if it sets the stack to zero, for a pointer variable that corresponds to the null-pointer. If the code have a null-pointer check then that would work. If not run in the debugger, then the stack memory will be indeterminate (seemingly random), and a pointer would not be null but seen as valid (because it's not null) which it isn't. When behavior differs when running inside compared to outside a debugger, usually uninitialized variables are to blame.

Comment: Nonetheless, given that the segfault reliably happens when neither gdb nor valgrind is used, the most straightforward way to debug it is to run without gdb or valgrind, let it generate a core, then analyze the core.  AFAICT, the questioner hasn't even tried that.